# Setup CNAME for multiple sub domains

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy

I added a CNAME record in GoDaddy

**.mirror -> ghs.googlehosted.com

My goal is to be able to point to a web app using username.mirror.xyz.com

However this works partially, the only thing that works is

test.mirror.xyz.com

Other than "test" nothing works, I do not understand why is this happening?

Comment: A problem description that consists only of "nothing works" is really not helpful. How are you testing? What results are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

`ghs.googlehosted.com` would need to know how to handle those subdomains. Google Apps lets you set up specific subdomains (i.e. `mail.example.com` going to your Google Apps mail), but I'm not aware of it being able to handle wildcards like this.

Comment: The curious thing here is test.mirror.xyz.com works, but 123.mirror.xyz.com and others won't work. Odd.

Comment: @xybrek Check your Google Apps console. Where does `test.mirror.xyz.com` take you, then check what's configured in the console for that service.